Exception while trying add Service
Here I added my services, its seems all done properly. its not my first time adding services.
var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);

builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");

builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Services.AddBlazoredToast();

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

//authonticstion and authorization services

builder.Services.AddAuthenticationCore();

builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();

builder.Services.AddScoped<ILocalStorageService, LocalStorageService>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider,CustomAuthenticationStateProvider>(); //problem here

await builder.Build().RunAsync();

CustomAuthenticationStateProvider Class:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using SapirProductionFloorManagment.Shared;
using System.Net.Http.Json;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class CustomAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly ILocalStorageService _localStorageService;

    public CustomAuthenticationStateProvider(HttpClient httpClient, ILocalStorageService localStorageService)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
        _localStorageService = localStorageService;
    }

    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var token = await _localStorageService.GetItemAsync("authToken");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        {
            // User is not authenticated
            return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity()));
        }

        try
        {
            // Ideally, you would decode the token and extract claims
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(ParseClaimsFromJwt(token), "jwt");

            // Create and return the authentication state
            var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            return new AuthenticationState(user);
        }
        catch
        {
            // Token is invalid or error occurred
            return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity()));
        }
    }

    public async Task LoginAsync(User user)
    {
        var response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("login/getloginrequest", user);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var token = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            await _localStorageService.SetItemAsync("authToken", token);
            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(GetAuthenticationStateAsync());
        }
    }

    public async Task LogoutAsync()
    {
        await _localStorageService.RemoveItemAsync("authToken");
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(GetAuthenticationStateAsync());
    }

    private IEnumerable<Claim> ParseClaimsFromJwt(string jwt)
    {
        var payload = jwt.Split('.')[1];
        var jsonBytes = ParseBase64WithoutPadding(payload);
        var keyValuePairs = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonBytes);
        return keyValuePairs.Select(kvp => new Claim(kvp.Key, kvp.Value.ToString()));
    }

    private byte[] ParseBase64WithoutPadding(string base64)
    {
        switch (base64.Length % 4)
        {
            case 2: base64 += "=="; break;
            case 3: base64 += "="; break;
        }
        return Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
    }
}

The exception I get is:
blazor.webassembly.js:1 crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Cannot provide a value for property 'AuthenticationProvider' on type 'SapirProductionFloorManagment.Client.Shared.MainLayout'. There is no registered service of type 'CustomAuthenticationStateProvider'.
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property 'AuthenticationProvider' on type 'SapirProductionFloorManagment.Client.Shared.MainLayout'. There is no registered service of type 'CustomAuthenticationStateProvider'.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<CreateInitializer>g__Initialize|1(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IComponent component)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.PerformPropertyInjection(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IComponent instance)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.InstantiateComponent(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Type componentType)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InstantiateComponent(Type componentType)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InstantiateChildComponentOnFrame(RenderTreeFrame& frame, Int32 parentComponentId)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewComponentFrame(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 frameIndex)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewSubtree(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 frameIndex)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InsertNewFrame(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 newFrameIndex)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.ComputeDiff(Renderer renderer, RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, Int32 componentId, ArrayRange`1 oldTree, ArrayRange`1 newTree)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment, Exception& renderFragmentException)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderInExistingBatch(RenderQueueEntry renderQueueEntry)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()

Im using Blazor WebAssembly, tried a lot off methods to fix it, maybe something missing from my project??
can someone tell me the problem here.........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Maybe you are trying to resolve CustomAuthenticationStateProvider instead of AuthenticationStateProvider

If you are writing a custom authentication provider, are you supposed to add this line builder.Services.AddAuthenticationCore(); ?

Change the problem line to builder.Services.AddScoped<CustomAuthenticationStateProvider>();

Vital missing piece - Show us the code you are using to inject the service.

Find SapirProductionFloorManagment.Client.Shared.MainLayout file and add this line
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationProvider

to register it.
